# XML more specific validation through xsd assert

Tags: xml, xsd, assert, complextype

this is an schema that i need to improve to validate  by an assert that if `rule/type` has a value of `A` or  `B` then `Return = true`
in something like:

```
<xsd:assert test="if (@type$value = A or @type$value= B) then @return$value = true" />
```

this is the XSD that I already have been working :

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:simpleType name="Rule">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="C"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="D"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="E"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="cType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="C-val1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="C-val2"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="C-val3"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="DType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="D-val1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="D-val2"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="D-val3"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:element name="Rule">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Type" type="Rule"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Return" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:choice>
                        <xsd:element name="BConfig"/>
                        <xsd:element name="AConfig"/>
                        <xsd:element name="CConfig" type="CRule"/>
                        <xsd:element name="DConfig" type="DRule"/>
                        <xsd:element name="EElement" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    </xsd:choice>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="CRule">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="C" type="CType" maxOccurs="3" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="DRule">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="D" type="DType" maxOccurs="3" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

But don't know how to use asset correctly

UPDATE 1:

following  sergiofc this is the updated schema

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:simpleType name="Rule">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="C"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="D"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="E"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="cType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="C-val1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="C-val2"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="C-val3"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="DType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="D-val1"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="D-val2"/>
        <xsd:enumeration value="D-val3"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:element name="Rule">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="Type" type="Rule"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Return" type="xsd:boolean"/>
                    <xsd:choice>
                        <xsd:element name="BConfig"/>
                        <xsd:element name="AConfig"/>
                        <xsd:element name="CConfig" type="CRule"/>
                        <xsd:element name="DConfig" type="DRule"/>
                        <xsd:element name="EElement" type="xsd:integer"/>
                    </xsd:choice>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:assert test="if (Type = ('A', 'B')) then Return = true() else true()"/>
            </xsd:restriction>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="CRule">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="C" type="CType" maxOccurs="3" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="DRule">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="D" type="DType" maxOccurs="3" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

but i still don't know where to locate the `xsd:assert`, i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I tried `<xsd:assert test="if (@Type = 'A' ) then @Return = true "/>` but the xsd isn't valid itself `S4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The Content Of '#AnonType_Rule' Is Invalid. Element 'assert' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often.`

Comment: (a) are you using an XSD 1.1 processor, (b) if you are, it's telling you that the xs:assert is in the wrong place, so if I'm going to help you, you're going to have to tell us where it is.

Comment: michael I supose  your question was answered but also,  im using oxigen with xerces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well you want `Return` value to be true if `Type` value is `A` or `B`. If so, you can use this assertion:

```
<xsd:assert test="if (Type = ('A', 'B')) then Return = true() else true()"/>
```

Explanation:

1. You should only use `@name` to get an attribute named `name`, you must not use `@` if you are selecting an element, `name` is enoug to select an element named `name`.
2. `$value` is a variable that is only present in `<xs:assertion>` for simple values, it is not present in `<xs:assert>`.
3. In XPath an expression like `'val2' = ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')` returns true if some element in the left is present in the right sequence., although your or approach is also valid.

If you wish, you can read XPath specs or an XPath tutorial to gain better knowledge of it.

Comment: yes you are exactly right, I need to read more about it , but i haven't found a digestible source of knowledge on this subject , i just knew it was possible.  is that so that i don't know where to locate it  inside my schema  or if i need to put it inside a restriction.

Comment: actually found that this worked correctly do you have like a  xml easy to chew reference?

Comment: Look at w3schools tutorials. They're not complete but they are easy

Answer (score 3):

Please follow this example:

It deals with conditional tests.

```
<xs:complexType name="ProductType">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="number" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="size" type="xs:integer"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="dept" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:assert test="if (@dept = 'ACC')
                   then number > 500
                   else if (@dept = 'WMN')
                   then number &lt;= 300 and number > 200
                   else if (@dept = 'MEN')
                   then number &lt; 200
                   else false()"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: actually this is the example from where I got the idea but I require access to the Type and Return  elements for this task and can seem to find a suitable example of this.